# What are patterns of event sourcing

Tags: apache-kafka, event-sourcing, system-design

What are some patterns you should follow in event source systems?

What are good ways to group events?

If your data is connected, service can try to consume event that cannot be processed yet.

Issue I have:
You could try to consume USER_CREATED and user can have roles.

What often happens is I still didnt consume ROLE_CREATED, so when consuming USER_CREATED, I am lacking that role.

In that case I retry for some time in case role appears. When it does I process it, which I am aware is bad solution.

Only other solution I could think of is grouping everything in a single event stream.

I could consume ROLE_CREATED and USER_CREATED then push that into local event stream which consists of ALL events happening to local service and process everything one by one.

USER_CREATED wont be ingested before ROLE_CREATED because I have 1 linearly merged event stream which still probably wont scale well as it's one by one.

Does such pattern exist?

Answer (score 0):

You should queue the data for users until you have roles available. Yes that means you may have to retry. That does not mean you need to retry from a *Kafka consumer*, though.

For example, dump roles into a database. When you consume a user creation event, insert some database record of `value=user,role=X,status=pending` (possibly add `updated_at` timestamp as well). Then scan that table with an external, periodic process that joins against any existing role table, when you get a matching role (one that's been consumed and written to the table), then you can update the status field to `creating`, then `created`, or `error`, etc. Then any queries to find one/all users is simply a lookup where `status=created`. This pattern will also work for user deletes, but may get confusing around role deletes (you'd need to modify all user records) and user updates (you could again get into the situation where a "update role for user" event doesn't know about the role yet).

This is almost what a KTable-KStream join is doing, but only on actively consumed data.

Comment: Im not retrying from kafka consumer now, but on app level. Tho it blocks everything. But you gave me an idea. I could use one more queue for retries..so i have 1 queue that is a "happy path" queue. Once something fails, I push it to a retry queue that has backoffs and stuff.

Comment: Right. Dead letter queues (DLQ) are the more common phrase for that